# How to make a JOptionPane stay opened

Tags: java, joptionpane

I have a JOptionPane which displays a custom panel. I've read that the option pane cannot be made to remain opened after pressing the OK button for example. Is that really true and if not how could it be done.

**EDIT**

I found this link very useful link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#stayup

Comment: You could always make your own popup window

Comment: @Chris I have two nested ones. And both get terminated after any of the buttons is pressed.

Comment: if Chris advice is not ok, then extend the class...

Comment: You can use JPanel/JFrames to make popups instead that you have more control over - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115745/making-a-jpanel-popup Then you can customize what you want the buttons to do

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example with image when `JComboBox` located on `JOptionPane` and it is staying after clicking in `JComboBox`:
[Force JOptionPane to Stay Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821667/force-joptionpane-to-stay-open)

```
 ...
    JComboBox optionControl = new JComboBox(options);
         optionControl.setSelectedIndex(3);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, optionControl, "Option",
         JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
  ...
```